I'm finding it difficult to bake my textures to after building an African village as a beginner
I've built a scene all together in one (1) .blend file;

I used a plane as ground (earth) and applied the scale (Ctrl + A).
I used shader nodes for texture. No subdivision/ through cut.
I used planes for/ as buildings (houses) walls. I joined (Ctrl + J) to form a unit (house). No subdivision
I used planes for roofing. Image textures were used. No subdivision or through cut
I used cube as wood for roofing joints I only used UV Editor to
place/ reposition a mesh on the image texture
I imported trees into the scene.

Blender has been lagging or shutting down abruptly.

What can/ should do i to reduce lagging or abrupt shut down at least?

How can i bake all texture, if possible, into one (1)?



The question is unclear and impossible to answer as it is currently written. You should edit it and form a clear question providing full context, screenshots, a .blend file if possible and all the other relevant information. Baking is simply saving the result of some calculations in some way. There are many ways to bake many things. If you have a question about it, you should specify what exactly you want to bake.

Hello and welcome. What do you mean "bake everything". Baking is generally used to convert materials into static images, it will not magically fixing crashes. This sounds like the XY Problem, maybe you should look into what is causing those crashes. Have you updated your drivers, does your scene fit the available memory. Is it taxing your computer? Could you clarify what you want to bake exactly?

Another thing that's called baking is computing the frames for physics simulations, but I don't see you mention any simulations in the question, so there's nothing to bake there either.
